# Python из Json запроса выбрать необходимый элемент

Tags: python, массивы, json

Как найти элемент из Json запроса, который

идет начинается с 'symbol' == eosusd, и значение его поля 'amount'?

Текущий запрос

```
bitfinex.privatePostPositions()
```

выдает следующий ответ

```
Current bitfinex position($): [{'id': 135742248, 'symbol': 'ethusd', 'status': 'ACTIVE', 'base': '730.0', 'amount': '0.77825165', 'timestamp': '1520654412.0', 'swap': '-0.02546778', 'pl': '-178.2227408566'}, {'id': 136434143, 'symbol': 'eosusd', 'status': 'ACTIVE', 'base': '7.84538786', 'amount': '-4.53', 'timestamp': '1523885100.0', 'swap': '-0.00000017', 'pl': '-0.5318489082'}]
```

Как изменить запрос так, получать значение **-4.53** из ответа

---

Методом проб и ошибок добрался до
bitfinex.privatePostPositions()[1]['amount']

что крайне неправильно, тк удаление элемента 0 повлечет ошибку на запрашиваемый элемент 1

Comment: А зачем удалять элемент 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем разобрался, как-то так

```
current_bitfinex_position = bitfinex.privatePostPositions()
current_bitfinex_position = [item for item in current_bitfinex_position if item['symbol'] == market_l][0]['amount']
```